# Jquery not functioning correctly (not waiting?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my javascript:

```
  $('#Service').val("2");
  $("#Service").change(); // Sets new options in subservice.
  $('#Subservice').val("5");
  //EDIT:
  alert($('#Subservice').length); // Returns 1, when there are far more in it.
```

Service and Subservice are drop down boxes.

On Service change, the new list of subservices is populated.

This is setting the fields of the record to be editted. It executes when I click an Edit Button. 
It sets the service dropdownbox, then is populating the subservice dropdown box, then attempting to set the correct dropdown selection for it.

However it is not correctly setting the subservice box. The options are correct, so `.change()` is working and service sets correctly. However Subservice is not being set. And there is an entry with value 5 in it.

My only reasoning is that .change is firing, but carrying on to setting .val before it finishes. And so no options exist at the time of setting. However I dont see why it would be threading either. So Im not sure what is going on or how to fix it.

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo? It's likely that the event handlers are executed only after the current code block terminated.

Comment: Using `alert($('#Subservice').length);` is returning 1. Aka nothing in the list :o

Comment: I think @FelixKling is probably correct, the execution of the `change` event handler occurs *after* the current code block has finished. That would definitely be true if the callback function was using an AJAX request.

Comment: the change() event contacts the server via `$.getJSON`.  Which I believe is AJAX. But Without rewriting the population code for this one event, Im unsure how I can access its callback event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change last line in your code as

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#Subservice').val("5");
}, 10);
```

Comment: Why? I'm not saying you're not correct (I happen to think you are), but the answer really isn't worth anything if you don't explain **what** the problem is and **why** this fixes it.

Comment: I assume this is adding a 10ms delay before running? Either way, it is not working, Ill try increasing delay.EDIT: With 1000 it is working. This seems prone to error depending on how long it takes to load, plus adding unnecessary delay in most cases, i.e. it doesnt trigger when loading complete, but instead after a given time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put your code in the ready function ?

```
$(function () {
  $('#Service').val("2");
  $("#Service").change(); // Sets new options in subservice.
  $('#Subservice').val("5");
});
```

This will wait for the entire DOM to be ready before executing the code in the function, making #service available.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, it executes on an edit button click.

Comment: Oh ok sorry. You should add a jsfiddle of your code then, or at least the part where you set #Service and #Subservice.

Comment: The change event contacts the server and obtains the subservices. Not sure how to dummy this in Javascript/ Jsfiddle. Its definately something to do with it not having loaded, as the delay answer works with a second delay. Not really a feasible solution though.